# What does it mean to find a linear combination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am going through Gilbert Strang's Intro To Linear Algebra class. I believe I am misunderstanding how the questions in the textbook are written, however.

The first question of section 1.3 is:

**Find the linear combination $3s_1 + 4s_2 +5s_3=b$**

My understanding of a linear combination was that it was the multiplication of matrices itself that creates a linear combination of the columns.

So, is the answer here:

$\begin{bmatrix}s_1 & s_2 & s_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}$ = b?

I am confused on the rest of the question as well. It states to:

**Write b as a matrix-vector multiplication multiplication $Sx$ with 3,4,5 in $x$. Compute the three dot products (row of S)$\cdot x$  such that the following go into columns of S:
$\\ s_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}, s_2 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}, s_3 = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} $**

Then, is this asking me to set the question up in the following form:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
                1 & 1 & 0 \\
                1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix}$

And then solve to get

$b = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 0 \\
                3 & 4 & 0 \\
                3 & 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$?

I know this question is long winded and basic, but understanding what's being asked would be really helpful for me

Comment: The multiplication of a $3 \times 3$ matrix and a $3 \times 1$ matrix is a $3 \times 1$ matrix. So $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
                1 & 1 & 0 \\
                1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 7 \\ 12\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Michael, ah that's right. So, then it would be $\begin{bmatrix}3\\
                7\\
                12\end{bmatrix}$?

Okay, thanks. Then, those are my three dot products that were requested in the question?

Comment: Yes.  This is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix.  A linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ produces another vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Got it, and for the first part where no specific numbers were asked, was the form I put down correct?

Also, thanks a lot. I appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$3 \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}}_{s_1} + 4\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}}_{s_2} + 5\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}}_{s_3}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\
                1 & 1 & 0 \\
                1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{bmatrix} = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 7 \\ 12\end{bmatrix}}_{b}$$